# Flask/http- tell the client that the request needs some more time to complete

Tags: python, rest, http, flask

I have a web service(REST) where one request might take up to 30 sec to return an answer (lots of calculation). There is a risk, that during the calculation, the client webbrowser aborts(?) the existing connection and retries. Here is the console-output of the server-side:

```
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 53209)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tmx\Anaconda2\lib\SocketServer.py", line 290, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Users\tmx\Anaconda2\lib\SocketServer.py", line 318, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Users\tmx\Anaconda2\lib\SocketServer.py", line 331, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Users\tmx\Anaconda2\lib\SocketServer.py", line 654, in __init__
    self.finish()
  File "C:\Users\tmx\Anaconda2\lib\SocketServer.py", line 713, in finish
    self.wfile.close()
  File "C:\Users\tmx\Anaconda2\lib\socket.py", line 283, in close
    self.flush()
  File "C:\Users\tmx\Anaconda2\lib\socket.py", line 307, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

One option is what I thought of is to somehow notify the client that "I'm alivem but the request is still needs some more time", or to somehow set the timeout on server side. What are the possibilities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to run code in Flask after you've already returned some data. Your options are to either use something like a task queue (see [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/)), or to yield your response in multiple parts.

Views in Flask can return strings, but they can also return iterables that contain strings. So you could return `"abc"`, `["abc"]`, or a generator that will yield `"abc"`. If you do your processing between yields, data will get sent to the client while the request is still running.

Take a look at the following example:

```
def generator_that_does_the_calculation():
    sleep(1)
    yield "I'm alive, but I need some time\n"
    sleep(1)
    yield "Still alive here\n"
    sleep(1)
    yield "Done\n"

@app.route('/calculate')
def calculate():
    return Response(generator_that_does_the_calculation())
```

Comment: Hmm, sounds reasonable. Though I get a TypeError: 'generator' object is not callable. Any idea?

Comment: Try returning a `Response(generator_that_does_the_calculation())`

Comment: thanks, this way it works. Please update your original answer :)